# Find the smallest integer k such that $n \le \lceil(3/2)^k\rceil$

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given $f(n) \le 1+f(\lfloor(2n/3)\rfloor)$. We need to find the smallest integer k such that $n \le \lceil(3/2)^k\rceil$ and give an upper bound for $f(\lceil(3/2)^k\rceil)$.

I already know that $\lfloor2/3\lceil(2n/3)^i\rceil\rfloor \le \lceil(3/2)^{i-1}\rceil$ and have the inequality that $f(\lceil(3/2)^k\rceil) \le 1+\lceil(3/2)^{k-1}\rceil$. I have no idea how to process.

Comment: Isn't it $k=\lfloor \log_{3/2} n \rfloor$?

Comment: May I ask how to calculate $\lceil(3/2)^{\lfloor log_{3/2}n \rfloor}\rceil$? I think I'm supposed to cancel things out with $f(\lceil(3/2)^k\rceil)$.